# Create a fkInternalCalc field on TSQLQuery

Tags: delphi, lazarus, fpc

The following Delphi function can be used to add a fkInternalCalc to a TClientDataset.
This is useful because I can store some information for each record, make calculation or store temporary flag.

The same code does not work in Lazarus, it stops on *DataSet.FieldDefs.Update*.

Are there means to achieve the same functionality?
Remember that one could change database fields and apply the changes made.

A working Delphi code using the function is:

```
AddDummyField(qry,TIntegerField,'PROCESS_ACTION');
qry.Open;
...

function AddDummyField(Dataset:TDataset;fieldClass:TFieldClass;fieldName:string;size:integer):TField;
var
  i: Integer;
begin

  if Dataset.FieldDefs.Count = 0 then
  begin
    DataSet.FieldDefs.Update;

    for i := 0 to DataSet.FieldDefs.Count - 1 do
      DataSet.FieldDefs[i].CreateField(DataSet);
  end;

  Result := Dataset.FindField(fieldName);

  if Result <> nil then
    exit;

  Result := fieldClass.Create(Dataset);
  Result.FieldName := fieldName;
  Result.FieldKind := fkInternalCalc;
  Result.DataSet := Dataset;

  if size>0 then
    Result.Size := size;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to open the dataset before.

```
...
DataSet.Open;
DataSet.FieldDefs.Update;
DataSet.Close;

for i := 0 to DataSet.FieldDefs.Count - 1 do
  DataSet.FieldDefs[i].CreateField(DataSet);
...
```